# How do I properly light a custom mesh in SceneKit without showing off the irregularities of the mesh?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, scenekit, arkit, metal

so I have this mesh below which I created. It was originally a .obj, but I converted it over to a .scn. This is how the mesh looks with default ambient lighting when viewing in SceneKit editor.

[image]

My issue is, that when I add a light to the scene it very badly shows off the mesh's geometry. For example, in the mesh below I add 4 omni lights around the mesh.

[image]

As you can tell, the top of the Apple shows of the individual polygons that make up the mesh. My main question is: is there something I can do to reduce this? There has to be some setting where I can feather how the light interacts with the mesh. I have attempted to turn off shadows but that didn't do anything.

Adding a bunch more lights also didn't fix the problem. You can still see those little polygons standing out upon getting closer.

Here is another example where I add a spot light looking directly down at the mesh. Here the polygon problems exists, but the entire apple also becomes extremely dark. Is there someway to light the apple up so it doesn't go completely dark so quickly without adding more lights?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that your mesh only has positions. You will also need per-vertex normals to get a smooth shading. Blender almost certainly has a tool to generate missing normals.

The lower part of the apple is dark because it doesn't get any light. You can add an [`.ambient`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlight.lighttype/1522769-ambient) light to your scene so that every object gets at least a minimum amount of light.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

myNode.geometry.subdivisionLevel = 1

(where myNode is the SCNNode, that holds the Apple Geometry from your SCN File)

This should at least smooth the surface.